# 12.04 Wifi Problems

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I recently wiped my hard drive and installed ubuntu 12.04 on my hp sleekbook 6. Everything in the installation went alright and I installed all the updates. The catch is that I can only be on the internet via Ethernet cord. My wifi just continues to try to connect and then eventually drops then continues to try. I know the password is right too. Can anyone help me? I also have Uverse.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If [Ahmadego's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/277978/22949) doesn't help, then we'll need more hardware information to help you. In that case, please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Check for updated wireless card drivers. (Check additional drivers as well and **Activate** the driver if it wasn't active.